# "JUnitTask was not found" error (Hudson, Ant, JUnit)

Tags: ant, junit, hudson

I tried several ways to install ant and junit on the same server as hudson. I eventually downloaded the Ant source, installed the optional dependencies by using the included fetch.xml file, built the source code, and dropped junit-4.8.1.jar into the lib directory where the compiled ant code [that I just built] is. Then I set ANT_HOME to the ant root directory by using the "export ANT_HOME=/usr/share/ant" command. I also set a Hudson configuration variable of "ANT_HOME" with the same value (/usr/share/ant) and I also put a new file into the /etc/profile.d directory with the export ANT_HOME command as well. At this point I'm not sure what else to try, but Hudson still gives me the error:

> BUILD FAILED /var/lib/hudson/jobs/MyProject/build.xml:31: Problem:
>   failed to create task or type junit Cause: the class
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask was not found.
>           This looks like one of Ant's optional components. Action: Check that the appropriate optional JAR exists in
>           -/usr/share/ant/lib
>           -/var/lib/hudson/.ant/lib
>           -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument
>
> Do not panic, this is a common problem. The commonest cause is a
>   missing JAR.
>
> This is not a bug; it is a configuration problem

I did, in fact, check /usr/share/ant/lib and the class "org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.class" is located in the ant-junit jar file as I confirmed by running the command: `jar tfv ant-junit.jar | grep org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask`

Can someone please tell me what to try, I am not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Ubuntu you can simply apt-get ant; I did that and linked to the junit jar within my project.

Cheers,

Neil

Comment: what do you mean by "linked to the junit jar within my project"? are you talking about your hudson project? if so, what setting did you change? otherwise, did you mean within your ant build.xml script? (again, if so, please specify what you did). I tried all kinds of stuff including classpath entries, etc

Comment: Btw I am not on ubuntu. I am on centOS. When you said "linked to the junit jar" you meant ant-junit.jar, right? Since the junit.jar doesn't contain the class I was mentioning. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that hudson itself installs some version of Ant in one of its own libraries. I suppose that somehow caused a conflict because when I got rid of it, things worked. I think it is in /var/hudson or /var/hudson/lib. That path is added to the PATH environment variable during hudson installation. So your choice is either to add your own Ant install to the BEGINNING of the path, to delete hudson's version of Ant, or to delete that part of the PATH.